# Shortcut file opens location, but directly visiting location fails

Tags: vmware-fusion, shared-folders

Using VMWare Fusion 8.5's shared folders feature, which creates a Public desktop shortcut file to "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders". Opening this shortcut file takes me to the correct location, however if I try to use explorer to go to "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\", it does not work at all.

How is this even possible? I know that .lnk files can be kind of weird, but this just seems strange. To further complicate things it seems like I can `cd '\\vmware-host\Shared Folders'` in PowerShell just fine. Maybe .Net is somehow aware of this "network" location, but COM/lower levels aren't?

I should also note that this is on macOS Sierra, the guest VM is Windows 10 build 1607.

Comment: I notice you are trying to go to \vmware-host\shared folders from explorer. The first \ being just one. What if you type \\ there instead? Does that work?

Comment: Sorry that's a typo. Edited post to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following registry entry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order`

Name: `ProviderOrder` 

Type: `REG_SZ`

Data: `”RDPNP, LanmanWorkstation,webclient”`

Modify it to:

Data: `”vmhgfs,RDPNP, LanmanWorkstation,webclient”`

Look also to the VMware Technology Network:
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/524951